# Is "these couple sentences" acceptable English?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: my own example

Example:

> Hey, George, could you please review **these couple sentences** for accuracy for me?

Do you think everything is okay with the grammar?

Comment: My choice would be "George, could you review a couple of sentences for me please?" "Hey" as an attention getter is unnecessary and could be considered rude. "for accuracy" is redundant. "these couple sentences" is not correct, either "these sentences" or "a couple of sentences"

Comment: It's not just "a couple of sentences". It's THESE couple of sentences.

Comment: @CookieMonster Did you mean to leave the *of* out there, or was that a mistake?

Comment: I did. It's not a mistake.

Comment: I'd also consider "George, could you review these few sentences for me please?", or even "George, could you review these sentences for me please?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The grammar is perfectly fine**, *though it is something I never prefer to use.*

The "these" is the plural form of "this", used because the "couple sentences" is plural in number.

"These" is a determiner to refer to a specific object the speaker is "pointing" at in their speech. (In this case, the sentences to be reviewed.)

**However, *semantically*, the sentence is awkward. I would prefer using "a couple" and specify which objects in a different sentence.**

Comment: You cannot use "couple" in that phrase. It sound horrible. You could use a number, like two, but couple, no.

Comment: I think grammatically it's fine, but "these couple ___" is not simply not idiomatic in my (probably our) dialect of English. I personally would replace "a" with "these".

Comment: "THESE" is a precise word, "COUPLE" is an imprecise word, they do not go together. As Nihilist says, "THESE" refers to a specific thing, "COUPLE" when used to enumerate something is not specific.

Comment: @RonJensen Addressed.

Comment: @RonJensen I feel like that too, but it's ok for some speakers. I suspect you'd feel differently about *these last couple of months*. Look at what's happening to *these last couple* in published works over the last twenty years or so: [Ngram "these last couple of"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+couple+of%2C+these+couple+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20couple%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20couple%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of interesting points about the Original Poster's sentence.

*A couple* is sometimes used a bit like a number or numeral when it occurs with the word *more*:

- Can I have a couple more potatoes, please?
- Can I have two more potatoes, please?

However, in standard British English at least, when it is not used to modify another word like *less* or *more*, the phrase *a couple* works like a regular noun phrase like *a pair* or *a number* or *a group*. In the Original Poster's sentence we need the word *of*. Grammatically, "a couple" is not a numeral:

- four people
- three lemons
- two problems
- a group people (ungrammatical)
- a pair lemons (ungrammatical)
- a couple problems (ungrammatical)
- a group **of** people
- a pair **of** lemons
- a couple **of** problems

... it is not used like a number.

The second interesting point with the Original Poster's sentence is that it uses *these*. Although *couple* involves the idea of two things, like the word *group* it can be considered a countable noun. We can have one couple, two couples, three couples. If we are using the singular noun *couple* we often use it with a singular determiner:

- this couple was ...

However, when we use it in "couple of X" constructions, it often occurs with the plural determiner *these*:

- these past couple of weeks
- these couple of idiots

In my English, the Original Poster's sentence is a bit awkward but many native speakers would happily say:

- Hey, George, could you review these last couple of sentences here for me?

Comment: +1 for a Standard English answer. I do note, however, that the original speaker asks that George restrict his review to  matters of **accuracy**, which suggests that George is one of those obnoxious people who cannot resist correcting other people's "grammar". :)

Comment: @StoneyB. I actually interpreted OPs question as asking about grammatical accuracy, and he specifically mentions "grammar" and tags "grammaticality". Accuracy is ironically rather imprecise and thus somewhat redundant.

Comment: @Araucaria. Good answer. Syntactically it should be "this past couple of weeks" but semantically we are thinking of it as a number and the further apart the this/these and couple get the easier it is to make the specifier agree with semantic number rather than syntactic number. Also since OP's sentences are being introduced and are currently not in context or agreed to be reviewed, the indefinite article would be appropriate and I could not use this/these with couple. I have to choose: "these sentences" or "a couple of/few sentences" resp. emphasizes the particular sentences or their paucity.

Answer (score 9):

> Hey, George . . .

Beginning a sentence with *Hey,* is pretty conclusively diagnostic of an amicable colloquial register largely unconstrained by the niceties of formal expository prose.

In that context the sentence is unimpeachably "grammatical", at least in American speech.

- *Couple* without *of* is acceptable AmE.

  > Hey, George, we're headin over to the VFW for a couple beers. Wanta come?
- Consequently, *these couple* is just as acceptable as *those two* or *that dozen*.

  > I'm runnin over to Lowe's for those couple two-by-eights Jack ast for. You need any more 'n 'at?

It may look strange written out; but that's how even Very Highly Educated folks actually talk on my side of the pond.

Comment: You Westpondians sure talk strange ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria Yep, and we're proud of it.

Comment: +1, though I'm not sure that "could you please review ... for accuracy for me" fits quite the same colloquial register as your examples. Though sometimes even informal business-speak borrows otherwise-formal language (via bureaucratese and managementese), so I suppose it's possible.

Comment: This is reduction (in fast/informal speech): "couple of" reduces to sound like "coupla" and then to an indeterminate vowel (or syllabic L). As "couple" also reduces to a rather indeterminate vowel (or syllabic L), there can be little difference to hear (and so "couple beers" can take a life of its own).